# UrlRewriting with urlrewritingnet

Tags: .net, url-rewriting, web-config, urlrewriting.net

I want to rewrite url like below
http://www.abc.com/ac/ac0008 to http://www.abc.com/temp/urlRewriter.aspx?oldurl=/ac/ac0008

and

http://www.abc.com/ac/ac0008?vmid=233 to http://www.abc.com/temp/urlRewriter.aspx?oldurl=/ac/ac0008/vmid=233

so, In my urlrewritingnet rule is like this

```
  <add name="ac_redir1" 
  virtualUrl="^~/ac/ac0008?vmid=(.*)" 
  rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" 
  destinationUrl="~/temp/UrlRewriter.aspx?bike=y&amp;oldUrl=/ac/ac0008?vmid=$1"    
  ignoreCase="true" />
```

But this rule works for 1st url only, for 2nd url it sends only /ac/ac0008 and it doesn't send like this /ac/ac0008/vmid=233

Can anyone give me a sample rule for rewriting url with querystring parameters. Then I can get an idea to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have messed up your code.

For 2nd rule, new url will be like this,
~/temp/UrlRewriter.aspx?bike=y&oldUrl=/ac/ac0008?vmid=233"

then when you access to your query strings
as below

```
string oldurl = Request.QueryString["oldUrl"];
strign vmid =  Request.QueryString["vmid"];
```

now

```
oldurl = "/ac/ac0008"
vmid = 233
```

you wont get

```
oldurl = "ac/ac0008?vmid=233" at once :)
```

hope you get an idea.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I expected to get all the querystring parameteres at once.